# jQuery Animate icon to center, plus x pixels

Tags: jquery, icons, jquery-animate

I'm trying to have 3 icons animate to the center of a div. The problem I'm having is that they all animate to the center and end up on top of each other. I'd like them all separated by about 30 px. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(function(){
    $("#instagram").delay('1000').animate({right: $(window).width() / 2}, 200);
    $("#twitter").delay('1000').animate({right: $(window).width() / 2}, 150);
    $("#facebook").delay('1000').animate({right: $(window).width() / 2}, 100);
   });
```

It seems like it should be easy enough to add "+=30px" or "-=30px", but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. For me it was misplaced (). They need to enclose the math, not the position, in this case, "right". Working code below.

```
$(function(){
    $("#instagram").delay('1000').animate({right: ($(window).width() / 2) -30}, 200);
    $("#twitter").delay('1000').animate({right: $(window).width() / 2}, 150);
    $("#facebook").delay('1000').animate({right: ($(window).width() / 2) +30}, 100);
   });
```